# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

Estou com dificuldade de encontrar a solução para esse problema, no código quero passar da activity "MainActivity" para "PlantaList", mas na hora de testar o aplicativo na máquina virtual o app fecha depois dessa ação e no terminal exibe o seguinte erro:

> ```
> -17 16:05:44.130 2082-2082/com.example.adriano.campanha_flora_pre_alpha E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>          Process: com.example.adriano.campanha_flora_pre_alpha, PID: 2082
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.adriano.campanha_flora_pre_alpha/com.example.adriano.campanha_flora_pre_alpha.PlantaList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at com.example.adriano.campanha_flora_pre_alpha.PlantaList.onCreate(PlantaList.java:32)at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

Segue Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/campanha_flora_icon"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".PlantaList"/>
<activity android:name=".ConsultaAdapter" />
<activity android:name=".TelaCadastro"/>

</application>
```

Segue Main Activity

```
package com.example.adriano.campanha_flora_pre_alpha;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button botaocadastrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCadastrar);

botaocadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TelaCadastro.class));

    }
});

Button botaoconsultar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConsultar);

botaoconsultar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlantaList.class));

    }
});

Button botaopreferencias = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPreferencias);

botaopreferencias.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TelaCadastro.class));

    }
});
}
}
```

Segue PlantaList:

```
package com.example.adriano.campanha_flora_pre_alpha;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.GridView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PlantaList extends AppCompatActivity {

GridView gridView;
ArrayList<Planta> list;
ConsultaAdapter adapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.tela_consulta);

gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
list = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new ConsultaAdapter(this, R.layout.tela_consulta_2, list);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

// get all data from sqlite
Cursor cursor = TelaCadastro.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM PLANTA");
list.clear();
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    int id = cursor.getInt(0);
    String NomePopular = cursor.getString(1);
    String Especie = cursor.getString(2);
    String Familia = cursor.getString(3);
    String TipoDeRaiz = cursor.getString(4);
    String CorDeFlor = cursor.getString(5);
    byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(6);

    list.add(new Planta(NomePopular, Especie, Familia, TipoDeRaiz, CorDeFlor, image, id));
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

O que pode ser?

Comment: Verifique se `gridView`ou `cursor` é nulo.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo trecho de código

```
Cursor cursor = TelaCadastro.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM PLANTA");
```

que está na PlantaList, imagino eh que o sqLiteHelper não esteja inicializado.